# 3 state checkbox in advancedDataGrid when grouped using data as arrayCollection

Tags: apache-flex, flex4.5, flexbuilder, advanceddatagrid, flex-datagrid

I am looking for a 3 state checkbox added in advancedDataGrid when data is grouped, similar to the one i find in the search

http://techrays.wordpress.com/2008/02/18/a-3-state-checkbox-in-an-advanceddatagrid-itemrenderer/

this is really good other than its not working for an arrayCollection as a data provider, as it is using the XMLListCollection

I am not sure what changes need to be made in the file to make it work for arrayCollection

Please help!!!!

Comment: i changed few things and it is working fine now.

Comment: working on adding checkbox, expandAll and collapseAll icons  to the header and their functionality. please help me if somebody has already implemented this..